# How to modify object property before insertion into Blaze template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Let's say I have the following Blaze template helper that fetches some objects from a collection:

```
PackageInCart: function() {
            PackageIds = Carts.findOne({SessionId: SessionID}).Packages;
            var PackageObjects = Packages.find({ _id: { $in : PackageIds } } ).fetch();         
            return PackageObjects;
    },
```

The PackageObjects variable contains objects that have a 'priceperday' property with a certain price value. In the Blaze template, I can easily print this value using:

```
{{#each PackageInCart}}
 <div class="price">{{priceperday}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

However, what if I want to modify the 'priceperday' value from the Helper function before it gets printed in the template? What would be the correct way to do this?

One solution that came to mind was to make a for loop that iterates over the objects and does something like Object.defineProperty() to change the priceperday property into the new value.

I want to know if there's an easier or quicker way using Blaze methods to modify the object property that gets printed with the curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this using blaze you could do this using another helper.

```
weeklyPrice: function(priceperday){
  return priceperday * 7;
}
```

Which would be called like this

```
{{#each PackageInCart}}
  <div class="price">{{weeklyPrice priceperday}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

More info about spacebars helper arguments [in the docs](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/spacebars.html#Helper-Arguments)

Comment: Thanks! And if I understand correctly I would need to call the new helper from the PackageInCart helper? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Ah I read the docs and now it's clear. Thanks again for your answer.